# How to change process date on NodeJS instead of change system date directly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, process, environment-variables

I want to do some tests that needs alter process date when use Date class:

```
console.log(Date.now())
```

Running my program normally the process will get the machine current time:

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "node testDate.js"
}
```

Is there something like cross-env to change initial process date?

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "cross-env CURRENT_DATE=<future-date> node testDate.js"
}
```

Or is there a solution at runtime?

Can NodeJS change the process date like?

```
process.DATE_CLOCK=Date("<future-date>")

console.log(Date.now())// will print the future date + time passed after  previous line has been executed
```

Comment: you can send parameters to node script after node.js call. For example:
`$node testDate.js 1520978956795`
Than in Node you need to parse this timestamp string as number to Date constructor:
`var _date = new Date(parseFloat(process.argv[2]));`
and new Date object will be with timestamp that you send as parameter. For future dates you can send timestamp offset that you can add to Date.now()

Comment: Yes I know that!
But I want a global solution to simulate date with a future value or any other value! And not change in every part of code!

Comment: Did you find out a solution for this?

Comment: at the top of the file can you add 
```if(process.env.testFlag==true))Date.now = () => {
  return new Date().getTime() - 60 * 60 * 1000;
};```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible via an existing node env var but you should
checkout the [mockdate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockdate) package.

Here is an example using in unit tests.

```
// mut.js
module.exports = {
    getCurrentDate: () => Date.now()
}


// mut.test.js
const mut = require('./mut');
const mockdate = require('mockdate');

describe('mut', () => {
    const mockedTime = 1609865118363;

    it('should return adjusted date', () => {
        mockdate.set(mockedTime);
        expect(mut.getCurrentDate())
            .toEqual(mockedTime);
    });

    it('should return current date/time', () => {
        mockdate.reset();
        expect(mut.getCurrentDate())
            .not.toEqual(mockedTime);
    });
});
```

If you insist on adding it via a node env you could add a process env check similar to Sengupta Amit comment and wrap your application entry point. This would set the time similar to how you are requiring above.

```
//testDate.js
// CURRENT_DATE=1609865118363 node ./testDate.js

const mockdate = require('mockdate');
const mut = require('./mut');
const currentDate = process.env.CURRENT_DATE;
if (currentDate) mockdate.set(parseInt(currentDate));

console.log(mut.getCurrentDate()); // will log 1609865118363 to console
```

**EDIT:**
Have also tested this with Express and Node Http Server. It still works and will return Date header with time set via mockdate also.

```
// CURRENT_DATE=1609865118363 node testDate.js
const app = require('express')();
const mockdate = require('mockdate');
const currentDate = process.env.CURRENT_DATE;
if (currentDate) mockdate.set(parseInt(currentDate));

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send());

app.listen(3000, (err) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
})
```

[image]

```
const mockdate = require('mockdate');
const currentDate = process.env.CURRENT_DATE;
if (currentDate) mockdate.set(parseInt(currentDate));

const http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

[image]

Comment: That won't work for dates set internally by Node.js for example the date header set by http servers because those dates are maintained by node internally rather than externally by the user. (mockdate is a less-popular version of @sinon/fake-timers also used by jest which I help maintain that takes a similar approach)

Comment: Have tested both Express and plain vanilla http server and it will overwrite the time in the response headers. I may not be interpreting the context of your comment correctly and you are correct there may be some cases that this may not work.

Comment: try on modern Node (> 15.2.0), I added the bounty to see if someone can work around https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers/issues/344